# Binding property to a method in IronPython, wpf

Tags: wpf, ironpython

I am working in IronPython

I am trying to bind the foreground of list box item to a method

In order to see what is the right way I created a simple c# application
In which the XAML looks like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SetForeground x:Key="SetForeground"  />
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SetForeground}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Options"  Margin="15,15,15,0" >
            <ListBoxItem Content="Element 2"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Element 3"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Element 4"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Element 5"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Element 6"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also created a class named SetForeground which looks like this

```
public sealed class SetForeground : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Brushes.Brown;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I activated the project and it worked

Now I wanted to do the same solution in IronPython but I encountered with the
problem of what namespace to write in the following XAML statement (In the window header)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
```

can you help ?

are there any other adjustments that have to be made in transforming the solution to IronPython?